# Floor and ceiling Functions Equal?

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I know, logically it makes sense that the floor and ceiling both equal x, when x is an integer. Any proofs I've read really only use reasoning to explain this. I'm wondering if there is a way to use inequalities to prove this instead?

I know that it is stated here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Under relations among functions, but I'm unsure of how they arrived there.

Comment: Just apply the definitions. What *are* your definitions for the floor and ceiling functions?

Comment: They are defined as the largest/smallest integers $\le,\ge$, so they must be integer valued. If $x$ is an integer, there is not much room for anything else.

Comment: If $a\ge b$ and $b\ge a$ then $a=b$

Comment: Thank-you, I switched computers to add more input. I hope it clarifies what I'm attempting. The first is more of a "logic" proof, whereas the second uses inequalities. I'd prefer the inequalities if possible.

Comment: The `proof` part looks fine to me. However, I don't understand the `additionally` part. What is that supposed to prove? You already established that $\lfloor x \rfloor = x = \lceil x \rceil$ in the previous step. Or, otherwise put, what do you find unsatisfactory with the first part?

Comment: Thanks! I'll clarify the **Additionally** section, it should say **OR**...as in a second option/seperate proof that $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil$

Comment: After the edit, I still don't understand the difficulty with the `OR` part. If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $\max \{m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m \le x\} = x$ since obviously $x \le x$ and $x+1 \gt x$, so $\lfloor x \rfloor = x$. It follows the same way that $\lceil x \rceil = x.\;\; $(Also note that you transcribed the wikipedia definitions wrong - the free variable in the definition of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $m$ *not* $x$, same for $\lceil x \rceil$.)

Comment: Thank-you for the note! I guess my issue is that I was hoping to prove it more mathematically vs. using general logic. But, I think I've got a good proof that I like. I can add it in.

Comment: Sorry, but I am lost at what you mean by `prove it more mathematically vs. using general logic`. My previous comment mathematically meant that - when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ - the set $A = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m \le x\}$ includes $x$ and does not include $x+1$, therefore $\max A = x$, and all of that follows straight from the respective definitions. Don't know and can't guess what else you have in mind, so this will be my last comment here.

Comment: We have $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$ and $x\le\lceil x\rceil$. Now if $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lceil x\rceil=n$, what do we get from these two?
$$x\le n \text{ AND }n\le x$$

Comment: @dxiv - sorry to be confusing. I think it's just a matter of style/a certain look that I'm going for. The proof is fine as is, I'll be using it. I'm just so used to lines and lines of numbers that I have to remind myself that some proofs are just shorter than others. Thank-you for your help, it did help reassure me that what I had was just fine, and that more was not necessary.